# Where does Spark saves retrieved data on Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I would like to understand the difference between the `RAM` and `storage` in Azure databricks.

Suppose I am reading csv data from the Azure data lake (ADLS Gen 2) as follows:

```
df = spark.read.csv("path to the csv file").collect()
```

1. I am aware that the `read` method in spark is a `Transformation` method in spark. And this is not going to be run immediately. However, now if I perform an `Action` using the `collect()` method, I would assume that the data is now actually been read from the data lake by Spark and loaded into `RAM` or `Disk`. First, I would like to know, where is the data stored. Is it in `RAM` or in `Disk`. And, if the data is stored in `RAM`, then what is `cache` used for?; and if the data is retrieved and stored on `disk`, then what does persist do? I am aware that `cache` stores the data in memory for late use, and that if I have very large amount of data, I can use `persist` to store the data into a `disk`.
2. I would like to know, how much can databricks scale if we have peta bytes of data?
3. How much does the `RAM` and `Disk` differ in size?
4. how can I know where the data is stored at any point in time?
5. What is the underlying operating system running Azure Databricks?

Please note that I am newbie to Azure Databricks and Spark.

I would like to get some recommendation on the best practices when using Spark.

Your help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, I would like to know, where is the data stored.

When you run any action (i.e. collect or others) Data is collected from executors nodes to driver node and stored in ram (memory)

> And, if the data is stored in RAM, then what is cache used for

Spark has `lazy evaluation` what does that mean is until you call an action it doesn't do anything, and once you call it, it creates a `DAG` and then executed that DAF.

Let's understand it by an example. let's consider you have three tables `Table A`, `Table B` and `Table C`. You have joined this table and apply some business logic (maps and filters), let's call this dataframe `filtered_data`.  and now you are using this `DataFrame` in let's say 5 different places (another dataframes) for either lookup or join and other business reason.

if you won't persist(cache) your `filterd_data` dataframe, everytime it will be referenced, it will again go through joins and other business logic.  So it's advisable to persist(cache) dataframe if you are going to use that into multiple places.

By Default `Cache` stored data in memory (RAM) but you can set the storage level to `disk`

> would like to know, how much can databricks scale if we have petabytes of data?

It's a distributed environment, so what you need to do is add more executors. and may be need to increase the memory and CPU configuration,

> how can I know where the data is stored at any point in time?

if you haven't created a table or view, it's stored in memory.

> What is the underlying operating system running Azure Databricks?

it uses `linux` operation system.
specifically `Linux-4.15.0-1050-azure-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial`

you can run the following command to know.

```
import platform
println(platform.platform())
```

Comment: Thank you @Shah for your detailed answer. Regarding your first answer, If I assume that I have 10 transformation operations on a dataframe, and if i maintain a reference for each one of them `df1, df2, ..., df10`, then if I say for example: `df11 = df6.map(lambda x: x**2)`; then I assume that all previous dataframes `df1 to df6` will be evaluated again, "after I perform an action on `df11`?" Is that correct? 

Second, can I save data into the disks of the worker nodes and not on the `driver` node?

Comment: Finally, if I'm writing back to the cloud storage, what happens in the backend? Do the worker nodes perform the write operations, or is it the Job of the driver node? And can we parallelize this operation "Writing to cloud storage, i.e., ADLS Gen 2"? I would highly appreciate if you can address these questions by editing your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @I.A you've got it. right.. all the operation will be executed again. that's when you should use `cache` or `persist`.  when cache dataframe it's on `ram` distributed on `executors`. When you save as table or persist on disk , it's also distributed.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about last question. However, I think writing is also been taken care by executors.